# How to create a copy of mdb access and convert it's copy into csv on a same folder?

Tags: vb.net

conns = New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & "Data Source=" + newpath + "\DDCOS.mdb")

```
    If Not File.Exists(newpath + "\DDCOS.mdb") Then
        catNewDB.Create("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & "Data Source=" + newpath + "\DDCOS.mdb")
        Dim cmdd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("CREATE TABLE DDCOS( " & _
           "RecNum int identity," & "ZipFile NVarchar(50)," & "DvdName NVarchar(50)," & "SeqNo1 NVarchar(50)," & "SeqNo2 NVarchar(50)," & _
        "JobCode NVarchar(50)," & "ClientCode NVarchar(50)," & "TotalImages NVarchar(50)," & "TotalRecs NVarchar(50)," & "BatchCount NVarchar(50)," & "BatchDate NVarchar(50)," & "BatchSize NVarchar(50)," & "CONSTRAINT [pk_RecNum] PRIMARY KEY (RecNum)) ", conns)
        conns.Open()



        cmdd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        conns.Close()
        GC.Collect()
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()
    End If
```

The above code was my code on creating database. And now I'm about to create a copy on it and convert the copy into csv. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim countOfMdb = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.mdb").Count()
```

or

```
Dim countOfMdb = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.mdb").Length
```

if you want to include sub-directories:

```
Dim countOfMdb = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.mdb", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length
```